# How to specify correct url/path to a parent object only by its ID?

Tags: ruby, routes, nested, relational-database, ruby-on-rails-6

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :customers do
    resources :orders
  end

  resources :orders, :only => [:index]
```

I separated index for orders intentionally to list all *orders* of all *customers*.

I was able to access a particular field of a parent object by (I believe I had to put this calculation in a helper):

```
<%= Customer.find(order.customer_id).clinic_name %>
```

But can't figure out, how to specify correct path to the `customer_path`, so that it will take to its parent object's show page.
For now, I've marked as *_what_to_put_here_* below, which I'm struggling to figure out?

```
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= order.doctor_name %></td>
    <td><%= order.patient_name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to <%= Customer.find(order.customer_id).clinic_name, 
                        customer_path(_what_to_put_here_) %></td>
    <td><%= order.note %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= order.doctor_name %></td>
    <td><%= order.patient_name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to order.customer.clinic_name, customer_path(order.customer) %></td>
    <td><%= order.note %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```